# How to assign two arrays to a hash and correlate them by name basis in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I've got two arrays, both consisting of a list of filenames. The filenames are identical in both arrays except for the extension.

i.e. *filename.dwg* and *filename.zip*

Now, I've assigned each list of files to an array.

i.e. *@dwg_files* and *@zip_files*

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is check last modification date between two files of the same name in different arrays, then run a script if one is younger than they other. What I have so far seems to work except when it compares two files with different names. I need it to compare a file from the first array to the identical file in the other array.

i.e. *asdf1.dwg* should be correlated to *asdf1.zip*

```
my $counter = 0 ;
while ( $counter < @dwg_files ) {
    print "$counter\n";
    my $dwg_file = $dwg_files[$counter];
    my $zip_file = $zip_files[$counter];


#check if zip exists
if (-e $zip_file) {

     #Checks last modification date
     if (-M $dwg_file < $zip_file) {
         *runs script to creat zip*

     } else { 
         *Print "Does not need update."*
     }

} else {
    *runs script to create zip*
}

$counter++;
}
```

Doing some research, I figured I'd try to use a hash to correlate the two arrays. I just can't seem to figure out how to correlate them by name.

```
my %hash;
@hash{@dwg_files} = @zip_files;
```

I'm a complete Perl noob (just started working with it last week). I've been stuck on this for days, any help would be much apprecieted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take dwg file name, change extension to zip, and then proceed with checks,

```
for my $dwg_file (@dwg_files) {

    my $zip_file = $dwg_file;
    print "dwg:$dwg_file\n";
    $zip_file =~ s/[.]dwg/.zip/i or next;


  #check if zip exists
  if (-e $zip_file) {

       #Checks last modification date
       if (-M $dwg_file < -M $zip_file) {
           #*runs script to creat zip*

       } else { 
           #*Print "Does not need update."*
       }

  } else {
      #*runs script to create zip*
  }

}
```

Comment: print dwg files to check which one get skipped.

Comment: Better yet, replace ``for my $counter (0 .. $#dwg_files)`` with ``for my $dwg_file (@dwg_files)`` and skip the initialization of ``$dwg_file`` below.

Comment: @mzedeler OP prints `$counter` so it looks it's needed

Comment: `$counter` was used for `while` loop control in the question, so it is not necessarily needed (printing it seems like for debugging purposes)

Comment: @doubleDown it's now without counter.

Comment: It turns out it wasn't skipping the last one, rather it was skipping a file where the extension was capatilized; i.e. the extension is .DWG instead of .dwg. Is there a way to include .DWG in this line:

$zip_file =~ s/[.]dwg/.zip/ or next;

Comment: And yea the $counter was for debug purposes. Definitely don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

To store all of the filenames in a hash, you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

# grab all dwg and zip files
my @dwg_files = glob("*.dwg");
my @zip_files = glob("*.zip");

sub hashify {
   my ($dwg_files, $zip_files) = @_;
   my %hash;

   # iterate through one of the arrays
   for my $dwg_file ( @$dwg_files ) {
        # parse filename out
        my ($name) = $dwg_file =~ /(.*)\.dwg/;

        # store an entry in the hash for both the zip
        # and dwg files
        # Entries of the form:
        # { "asdf1" => ["asdf1.dwg", "asdf1.zip"]
        $hash{$name} = ["$name.dwg", "$name.zip"];
   }

   # return a reference to your hash
   return \%hash;
}

# \ creates a reference to the arrays 
print Dumper ( hashify( \@dwg_files, \@zip_files ) );
```

This is what the resulting hash looks like:

```
{
  'asdf3' => [
               'asdf3.dwg',
               'asdf3.zip'
             ],
  'asdf5' => [
               'asdf5.dwg',
               'asdf5.zip'
             ],
  'asdf2' => [
               'asdf2.dwg',
               'asdf2.zip'
             ],
  'asdf4' => [
               'asdf4.dwg',
               'asdf4.zip'
             ],
  'asdf1' => [
               'asdf1.dwg',
               'asdf1.zip'
             ]
};
```

Comment: Whats happening with ``@zip_files``? It's being created but not used.

Comment: @mzedeler They could use either array, I passed both in to illustrate that. I guess there could also be a case where you loop through both lists and *only* add the zip files that exist to the hash.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help. I've just got a quick question: when you use 
my @/dwg_files = glob("*.dwg");
my @/zip_files = glob("*.zip");
you populate the arrays based on files in the same directory. How would you populate arrays with files from a different directory (in this case a subfolder).

Comment: You can just specify the directory in the glob function, `print glob("$base_directory/*.zip");`